# FSCrawler on Windows _settings.yml, folders/directories and drives

Tags: windows, fscrawler

FSCrawler 2.7 on Windows server

For a given job eg test1 a _settings.yaml folder is automatically created

eg `c:\users\jbloggs\.fscrawler\test1\_settings.yml`

You need to specify where the documents you wish to crawl are located

fs:
url: "drive & folder of docs goes here"

url c:\tmp will cause an error

```
06:33:00,788 DEBUG [f.p.e.c.f.FsParserAbstract] Fs crawler thread [test2200] is now running. Run #1...
06:33:00,788 WARN  [f.p.e.c.f.FsParserAbstract] Error while crawling c: mp: c:  mp doesn't exists.
06:33:00,788 WARN  [f.p.e.c.f.FsParserAbstract] Full stacktrace
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of these formats is valid

```
url: "/c:/tmp" 
url: "c:\\tmp"
```

Doc are wrong here:
https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/tutorial.html#start-fscrawler

But correct elsewhere:

https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/ssh.html#windows-drives

also https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/local-fs.html#id2

Comment: Hey JohnC. Would you like to help fixing the documentation? I'd appreciate that a lot!